# How to display the button only in a certain window?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can i make this button visible only when the user goes to SelectionDisplay?

```
 <local:KinectHoverButton Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource KinectHoverButtonScrollLeftStyle}" Click="PageLeftButtonClick"   IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ControlsBasicsWindow, Path=PageLeftEnabled}"/>
 <local:KinectHoverButton Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource KinectHoverButtonScrollRightStyle}" Click="PageRightButtonClick" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=ControlsBasicsWindow, Path=PageRightEnabled}"/>
```

Right now, the button is public everywhere and I want it public in only one place.

I know this can be done by seeting a property of this kind and then input it in .xaml through databinding.

```
public bool IsSelectionDisplay
    {
        get { return IsSelectionDisplay; }
        set
        {
            if (//condition)
              {
                 //code

              }
        }
    }
```

What I don't know is what I should write in "setter" so that the button would be displayed only in a certain window.

http://i61.tinypic.com/ic4nc8.png

http://i58.tinypic.com/2ius7c.png

Comment: Your getter will lead to a stack overflow due to an infinite recursion. What do you *actually* want to return from there? The value of a dependency property, or the value of a private field? In both cases, the contents of the setter should then be obvious.

Comment: If there's nothing to set from outside the object, you don't need a setter.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a value converter. So bind the Visibility property

```
Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
      AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Name}"
```

Then in the Value Converter, do something like:

```
if (value.ToString() == "Window1") return Visibility.Visible;
```